# Trying to upvote own comment crashes Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, up-votes

Whenever I try to upvote my own comment in Android app (1.0.47), the app crashes*.

Galaxy S III running Android 4.4.2

---

(*) Yes, I know I'm not supposed to vote on my own comments... actually at first I did not know what that new `^` button does, since it's not similar to any desktop icon.

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.4, App version 1.0.47. *Hint: next time, long-press the button to get the tooltip ;)

Comment: Repro'd on S3-mini, Android 4.2.1, 1.0.47.  The upvote seemed to succeed then the app crashed - screen completely black, I had to restart the device.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in version 1.0.48, thanks!